# Is it worth to solo with 1Gh?

Tags: ether, hashrate, solo-mining

I've just completed my first Gh and i'm really thinking to solo mine, is it worth? what's the variance?
i know it can be shorter or longer to find a block, but what's the medium variance?

I'm currently mining on dwarf, but it's mining 20% lower than what's expected on the calculator and this is really bothering me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Poisson table](https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/vetri/public_html/statistics/poisson.pdf) to determine how many blocks you can expect to find in a given amount of time. For example, at 1 Gh, the *expected* value of how long it will take you to find a block is 9 days (Network difficulty is ~800TH and you have 1GH/s, so 800TH/(1GH/s) = 800000 seconds). So in a 27 day period, *assuming difficulty does not rise*, you can go to the column labelled 3 in the linked table (27 / 9 = 3) and see that, for example, you have a 5% chance of mining 0 blocks, 20% chance of mining 1 block, 42% chance of mining at most 2 blocks, etc. Of course, difficulty is rising quite quickly. I would peg the real *expected value* to find a block at around 2 or 2.5 weeks. If you can stomach that, solo mining does have a higher *expected* yield due to reduced latency and, of course, no fees.